# Add AVPlayerLayer as sublayer in each Collection View Cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, avfoundation

I have a custom view that I am embedding in each CollectionView cell. This view when given a URL checks to see if its a photo or video url and if its a video, it adds an AVPlayerLayer and sets the asset to the URL. If its an image, it adds an image view with that image.

```
import UIKit
import Kingfisher
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class MediaPlayerView: UIView {
    var mediaURL: URL? {
        didSet {
            determineMediaType()
        }
    }
    let videoExtensions = ["mov"]
    var asset: AVURLAsset?
    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer {
        return layer as! AVPlayerLayer
    }
    var player: AVPlayer?{
        get {
            return playerLayer.player
        }
        set {
            playerLayer.player = newValue
        }
    }
    override static var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return AVPlayerLayer.self
    }
    static let assetKeysRequiredToPlay = [
        "playable",
        "hasProtectedContent"
    ]

    private var playerItem: AVPlayerItem? = nil

    override init (frame : CGRect) {
        super.init(frame : frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        //determineMediaType()
    }

    func determineMediaType() {
        let url = self.mediaURL
        let pathExtention = url?.pathExtension
        print(url)
        print(pathExtention)
        if videoExtensions.contains(pathExtention!) {
            print("Movie URL: \(String(describing: url))")
            setupVideo(url: url!)
        } else {
            print("Image URL: \(String(describing: url))")
            setupImage(url: url!)
        }
    }

    func setupVideo(url: URL) {
        self.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        asset = AVURLAsset(url: url, options: nil)
    }

    func setupImage(url: URL) {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.frame = self.bounds
        imageView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth,.flexibleHeight]
        self.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
    }

}
```

Right now when this view is created it terminates with this exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalid', reason: 'layer <AVPlayerLayer: 0x60c000a26760> is a part of cycle
```

I think that its an issue because I am adding the playerLayer in the setupVideo function to self which has overridden LayerClass to always give AVPlayerLayer.self. AKA adding the player layer as a subview to itself. But Im not sure how to avoid this?

Comment: It is possibly a terrible design to add a AVPlayer to each cell in a collection view.. You might be better off adding placeholders for thumbnails and when tapped, they open a fullscreen video player..

Comment: Secondly, your layer is crashing because `self.layer` is a `AVPlayerLayer` and you are saying: `self.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)`.. but `self.layer` IS `self.playerLayer`.. They are the same layer so you are doing `self.layer.addSublayer(self.layer)` essentially.. that will crash.

Comment: @Brandon how would I add the player to the view then? Also, why is this such a terrible design and is there a different way to achieve this (I eventually want the videos to auto-play)